# Filter a list in Python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, filter

I have a list in Python

Username, Function, Project, Description, Date, Time, Year, Version

```
['erinil01', 'Oppstart', '', 'Startet programmet', '06/07/21', '12:48:54', '2021', '2']
['erinil01', 'Oppstart', '', 'Startet programmet', '06/07/21', '12:56:49', '2021', '2']
['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '920208', 'Lastet prosjektet', '06/07/21', '12:59:09', '2021', '2']
['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '920208', 'Lagret prosjektet', '06/07/21', '12:59:17', '2021', '2']
['erh4021', 'Oppstart', '', 'Startet programmet', '06/07/21', '13:02:38', '2021', '2']
['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '921106', 'Lagt til nytt prosjekt', '06/07/21', '13:06:45', '2021', '2']
['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '921107', 'Lagt til nytt prosjekt', '06/07/21', '13:07:02', '2021', '2']
['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '921106', 'Lastet prosjektet', '06/07/21', '13:07:08', '2021', '2']
```

Lets say I only want to filter this list based on different criterias, such as usernames, functions, projects, date, year etc.. If some filters are empty, then show all based on the other criterias.

Tips?

Comment: hello, what you mean by var3=''

Comment: add a proper example of your list with expected output

Comment: list has indexes - and you can check `if list[0] == 3 and list[1] == 5 ...` . And if you have it as nested list then you can use `for`-looo - like `for row in data: if row[0] == 3 and row[1] == 5 ...`. If you want to make more universal then criteria you should keep also as list or dictionary `{0: 3, 1: 5, 2: "", 3: 6}` and then you can use also `for`-loop to check every criteria. OR use `pandas.DataFrame` to make it simpler. Eventually you could keep it in `database` and use `SQL Query` for this.

Comment: You could provide some sample input and desired output to let people understand and help you.  And can you show what's been done so far?

Comment: what did you try? How do you keep this data - as nested list `[ [...], [...], ...]` or get from some source like `database` or `file`? In most situatuon you would run for-loop which get single `row` of data and check your criteria - by checking `row[0]`, `row[1]`, (etc.) with expected value.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say how you get this list but it looks rather like nested lists.

```
data = [
    ['erinil01', 'Oppstart', '', 'Startet programmet', '06/07/21', '12:48:54', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Oppstart', '', 'Startet programmet', '06/07/21', '12:56:49', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '920208', 'Lastet prosjektet', '06/07/21', '12:59:09', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '920208', 'Lagret prosjektet', '06/07/21', '12:59:17', '2021', '2'],
    ['erh4021', 'Oppstart', '', 'Startet programmet', '06/07/21', '13:02:38', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '921106', 'Lagt til nytt prosjekt', '06/07/21', '13:06:45', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '921107', 'Lagt til nytt prosjekt', '06/07/21', '13:07:02', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '921106', 'Lastet prosjektet', '06/07/21', '13:07:08', '2021', '2'],
]
```

and for nested lists you has to use `for`-loop to work with every row separatelly.

And for every row you can use index to check value.

This get all rows with empty value `Project` which has index `[2]`

```
filtered_data = []

for row in data:
    if not row[2]:
        #print('empty:', row)
        filtered_data.append(row)
      
print('--- filtered_data ---')

for row in filtered_data:
    print(row)
```

For more complex filter you have to create more complex `if`.

To make it more universal you can create function which gets single row and return `True` or `False` if you want to keep this row.

```
def selected(row):
    #if not row[2]:
    #    return True
    #else:
    #    return False
    
    # shorter
    return not row[2]

filtered_data = []

for row in data:
    if selected(row):
        #print('empty:', row)
        filtered_data.append(row)
```

And then you can even reduce it to list comprehension

```
filtered_data = [row for row in data if selected(row)]
```

or use function `filter()`

```
filtered_data = list(filter(selected, data))
```

This way you can create different functions `selected()` to combine filters.

```
filtered_data = list(filter(selected_1, data))
filtered_data = list(filter(selected_2, filtered_data))
filtered_data = list(filter(selected_3, filtered_data))
```

---

**BTW:**

If you get data from database then you could use `SQL query` to filter data directly when you get it from database.

If you could keep data in `pandas.DataFrame` then you could use column'n names `Username, Function, Project, Description, Date, Time, Year, Version` to filter it.

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working example

```
data = [
    ['erinil01', 'Oppstart', '', 'Startet programmet', '06/07/21', '12:48:54', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Oppstart', '', 'Startet programmet', '06/07/21', '12:56:49', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '920208', 'Lastet prosjektet', '06/07/21', '12:59:09', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '920208', 'Lagret prosjektet', '06/07/21', '12:59:17', '2021', '2'],
    ['erh4021', 'Oppstart', '', 'Startet programmet', '06/07/21', '13:02:38', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '921106', 'Lagt til nytt prosjekt', '06/07/21', '13:06:45', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '921107', 'Lagt til nytt prosjekt', '06/07/21', '13:07:02', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '921106', 'Lastet prosjektet', '06/07/21', '13:07:08', '2021', '2'],
]

# --- version 1 ---

filtered_data = []

for row in data:
    if (not row[2]) or (int(row[2]) > 920208):
        #print('empty:', row)
        filtered_data.append(row)
      
print('--- filtered_data ---')

for row in filtered_data:
    print(row)
    
# --- version 2 ---
    
def selected(row):
    #if (not row[2]) or (int(row[2]) > 920208):
    #    return True
    #else:
    #    return False
    
    # shorter
    return (not row[2]) or (int(row[2]) > 920208)
    
def selected_1(row):
    return not row[2]

def selected_2(row):
    return int(row[2]) > 920208

filtered_data = []

for row in data:
    if selected_1(row) or selected_2(row):
    #if selected(row):
        #print('empty:', row)
        filtered_data.append(row)
      
print('--- filtered_data ---')

for row in filtered_data:
    print(row)
    
# --- version 3 ---
    
def selected(row):
    return (not row[2]) or (int(row[2]) > 920208)
    
def selected_1(row):
    return not row[2]

def selected_2(row):
    return int(row[2]) > 920208

filtered_data = [row for row in data if selected(row)]
filtered_data = [row for row in data if selected_1(row) or selected_2(row)]
      
print('--- filtered_data ---')

for row in filtered_data:
    print(row)
    
# --- version 4 ---
    
def selected(row):
    return (not row[2]) or (int(row[2]) > 920208)
    
def selected_1(row):
    return not row[2]

def selected_2(row):
    return int(row[2]) > 920208

#filtered_data = list(filter(selected, data))
filtered_data = list(filter(lambda row:selected_1(row) or selected_2(row), data))
      
print('--- filtered_data ---')

for row in filtered_data:
    print(row)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Similar with `pandas`

```
data = [
    ['erinil01', 'Oppstart', '', 'Startet programmet', '06/07/21', '12:48:54', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Oppstart', '', 'Startet programmet', '06/07/21', '12:56:49', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '920208', 'Lastet prosjektet', '06/07/21', '12:59:09', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '920208', 'Lagret prosjektet', '06/07/21', '12:59:17', '2021', '2'],
    ['erh4021', 'Oppstart', '', 'Startet programmet', '06/07/21', '13:02:38', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '921106', 'Lagt til nytt prosjekt', '06/07/21', '13:06:45', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '921107', 'Lagt til nytt prosjekt', '06/07/21', '13:07:02', '2021', '2'],
    ['erinil01', 'Prosjektadmin', '921106', 'Lastet prosjektet', '06/07/21', '13:07:08', '2021', '2'],
]
    
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Username', 'Function', 'Project', 'Description', 'Date', 'Time', 'Year', 'Version'])
df = df.replace(r'', np.nan)  # to compare empty string with `float` value `920208`
print(df)

mask1 = df['Project'].isnull()  # detect `np.nan`
#print(mask1)

mask2 = (df['Project'].astype(float) > 920208)
#print(mask2)

filtered_data = df[ mask1 | mask2 ]  # `|` means `or` , `&` means `and`

print('--- filtered_data ---')

print(filtered_data)
```